# ionic - swapping elements in an ion-list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ion-list displaying a list of users using ng-repeat.
What i'm trying to do is to move one of the users from his position to the top whenever a notification is received, sort of like when you receive a message in a whatsapp chat. The array passed to the list is defined in the controller, as you will see in the following code.

listUsers.html:

```
<ion-view title="listaUsers" can-swipe-back="true">
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="false" scroll="true" class="has-header">
        <ion-list ng-repeat="session in listUsers">
            <a class="item item-avatar" href="#/app/profile/listUsers/chat/{{session.id}}">

                <img ng-src="http://sviluppo.asuscomm.com:43280/mob/ionic/immagini_{{session.social}}/{{session.id}}.jpg" err-SRC="img/default-user.png" />

                <h2>{{session.nome}} - {{session.cognome}}</h2>
                <p>{{session.messaggio}}</p>


                <div ng-if="session.in_out_struttura == 1">
                    <span class="badge badge-balanced">SI</span>

                </div>
                <div ng-if="session.in_out_struttura == 0">
                    <span class="badge badge-assertive">NO</span>
                </div>

            </a>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

listUsers.js:

```
angular.module('app.controllers')

.controller('listUsersCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $ionicLoading) {

    $scope.listUsers = []; 
    /*Some function will put the data into $scope.listUsers, 
      every element will be a JSON object like this:
        {
            id: 1,
            nome: "John",
            cognome: "Doe",
            social: "F",
            messaggio: "Some Message"
        }
    */

    //This function removes the record to move from the array and puts it back into it in first position
    $scope.putOnTop = function (id_usr, message) {
        for (var x = 0; x < $scope.listUsers.length; x++) {
            if ($scope.listUsers[x].id == id_usr) {
                var record = $scope.listUsers.splice(x, 1)[0];
                record.messaggio = message;
                $scope.listUsers.unshift(record); 
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //This listens to a custom event emitted from app.js
    $rootScope.$on("putUserOnTop", function (event, id_usr, message) {
        $scope.putOnTop(id_usr, message);
    });


})
```

app.js:

```
//This is just a part of the original app.js
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'ngCordova', 'ngCordovaOauth', 'ionic-datepicker'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $translate, $http, $state, $ionicHistory, $rootScope, $cordovaNetwork) {

    //...

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

        //...

        try {
            var push = PushNotification.init({
                android: {
                    senderID: "XXXXXXXXXX"
                },
                ios: {
                    alert: "true",
                    badge: "true",
                    sound: "true"
                },
                windows: {}
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR PUSH NOTIFICATION : " + e);
        }

        try {
            push.on('registration', function (data) {
                localStorage.setItem("registrationId", data.registrationId);
            });


            push.on('notification', function (data) {

                var senderId = data.additionalData.senderId;
                var destId = data.additionalData.destId;
                var message = data.additionalData.messaggio;

                //Checking if the app was in foreground, background or not running
                if (data.additionalData.coldstart !== undefined) {
                //THE WAS NOT IN FOREGROUND
                    if ($ionicHistory.currentView().url == "/app/profile/listUsers") {
                        $rootScope.$emit("putUserOnTop", senderId, message);
                    } else if ($ionicHistory.currentView().url == "/app/profile/listUsers/chat/" + senderId) {
                        //...
                    } else {
                        //...
                    }
                } else {
                    //THE APP WAS IN FOREGROUND
                    $rootScope.$emit("putUserOnTop", senderId, message);
                    //...
                }

            });

            push.on('error', function (e) {
                //...
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR : " + e);
        }

        //...

})

.config(...);
```

The problem is that if i run this code, the record is not moved in the list and no error is shown in console. If i run the `putOnTop` function using a button instead, it actually works fine. What am i missing?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I also tried to use `$cordovaPushV5` instead of `PushNotification`, modifing the code accordingly, but nothing changed, same behavior. Following is the updated *app.js*:

```
//This is just a part of the original app.js
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'ngCordova', 'ngCordovaOauth', 'ionic-datepicker'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $translate, $http, $state, $ionicHistory, $rootScope, $cordovaNetwork, $cordovaPushV5) {

    //...

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

        //...

        $cordovaPushV5.initialize({
            android: {
                senderID: "XXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            ios: {
                alert: "true",
                badge: "true",
                sound: "true"
            },
            windows: {}
    }).then(function() {
        // start listening for new notifications
        $cordovaPushV5.onNotification();
        // start listening for errors
        $cordovaPushV5.onError();

        // register to get registrationId
        $cordovaPushV5.register().then(function(registrationId) {
            localStorage.setItem("registrationId", registrationId);
        });
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:notificationReceived', function(event, data){
        var senderId = data.additionalData.senderId;
        var destId = data.additionalData.destId;
        var message = data.message;
        var timestamp = data.additionalData.timestamp;

        if (data.additionalData.coldstart !== undefined) {
            if ($ionicHistory.currentView().url == "/app/profile/listUsers") {
                $rootScope.$emit("putUserOnTop", [senderId, message, timestamp]);
            } else if ($ionicHistory.currentView().url == "/app/profile/listUsers/chat/" + senderId) {
                $rootScope.$emit("getMessages", {
                    senderId: senderId,
                    destId: destId
                });
            } else {
                $state.go("app.chat", {
                    userId: senderId
                });
            }
        } else {
            if ($ionicHistory.currentView().url == "/app/profile/listUsers") {
                $rootScope.$emit("putUserOnTop", [senderId, message, timestamp]);
            } else if ($ionicHistory.currentView().url == "/app/profile/listUsers/chat/" + senderId) {
                $rootScope.$emit("getMessages", {
                    senderId: senderId,
                    destId: destId
                });
            }

        }
    });

    // triggered every time error occurs
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:errorOcurred', function(event, e){
        //...
    });

    //...

})

.config(...);
```

Comment: Can you include your ng-repeat definition in your markup, it's hard to say how you are listing the items at the moment

Comment: Sorry, I messed up copy-pasting. Edited question to adjust the _listUsers.html_ part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just reporting that all I needed to make it work was putting `$scope.$apply();` in the `putOnTop` function, like this:

```
$scope.putOnTop = function (id_usr, message) {
    for (var x = 0; x < $scope.listUsers.length; x++) {
        if ($scope.listUsers[x].id == id_usr) {
            var record = $scope.listUsers.splice(x, 1)[0];
            record.messaggio = message;
            $scope.listUsers.unshift(record); 
            $scope.$apply() //<============================
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the way you get arguments from `$rootScope.$on`. The arguments will be in second argument like this :

```
$rootScope.$on("putUserOnTop", function (event, args) {
    var id_usr = args.id_usr;
    var message = args.message;
    $scope.putOnTop(id_usr, message);
});
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks. I tried this and the parameters are passed correctly, but the issue is still there. I verified all parameters using console.log inside the putOnTop function.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way you can achieve this is by using an angular filter: [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy). Especifically you can set an updated date property on your item and then filter by it in desc mode. e.g:

**Set filter**

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="session in listUsers | orderBy: '-updated_at'">
```

**Set updated_at**

```
$rootScope.$on("putUserOnTop", function (event, id_usr, message) {
    var user = $scope.listUsers.find(function() {
        return user.id == id_usr;
    });

    user.updated_at = new Date();
});
```

The `orderBy` filter will esentially re-order your items using the `updated_at` property and so each time a message is received you can set this timestamp to update your collection ordering.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your help.
I tried this but nothing happens. I can see all the correct data in console by using console.log, i can see the function finding the correct record and updating it, but on the list nothing changes UNTIL i tap on something (like back button or one of the list elements). In that case, i can see for a moment the data updating and then the view changes. Any ideas?

Comment: The reason might be the PushNotification service isn't within the context of angular, can you try wrapping your callback inside the $timeout(callback) service. Especifically wrap this callback `push.on('notification', callback)` within $timeout.

Comment: I tried this but did not work. I tried 

`$timeout(function(){push.on('notification', function (data) {...})},0);`, then 
`push.on('notification', function(){$timeout(function (data) {...}),0});` and then
`$timeout(push.on('notification', function (data) {...}),0);`

But none of them worked. The first one did not work at all, the orther two works just like before, so nothing change.

Comment: I edited my question with updated code after trying to use `$cordovaPushV5`.